# Json.dumps() ignores global initialized variables of a python object. Why?

Tags: python, json

This is a minimal example:

```
class TestObject:  
  name = "Test"

tObj = TestObject()  
out = json.dumps(tObj.__dict__)
```

out is here = {}

If I initialize the variable name after creating the object:

```
tObj = TestObject()
tObj.name = "Test"
```

out is going to be = {"name": "Test"}
Can someone explain why?

Comment: What do you mean? That is a *class variable*, not a global variable, and why would `tObj.__dict__` recognize a *global* variable, `tObj` is an instance of the `TestObject` class. The `__dict__` is the instance namespace. There are no instance variables, hence the instance namespace is empty.

Comment: The instance namespace `tObj.__dict__` and the class namespace `TestObject.__dict__` are different dicts.